# ORACLE Database query - trying to swap row values with multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written a query to swap the row values in the same table based on conditions in multiple tables

```
UPDATE LV_MESSWERT a1
SET a1.WERT_N = (
    SELECT mw.WERT_N
    FROM   LV_MPRG mp1, LV_PK   pk, LV_PKL pkl, VIEW_DEF3_MESSUNG mess, LV_MESSWERT mw, LV_DLOBJ dl, OSI_OBJ ob, LV_ABBRUCH ab 
    WHERE  (mp1.DEFMES_ID = mess.DEF_MESS_ID AND
          mp1.MPRG_ID = pk.MPRG_ID AND
          pk.PKL_ID = pkl.PKL_ID AND
             pk.PK_ID = mw.PK_ID AND
             mw.DLOBJ_ID = dl.DLOBJ_ID AND
             dl.obj_id = ob.obj_id AND
       mw.MW_ID = a1.MW_ID AND
       mw.SP = a1.sp AND
       ob.KENN = 'DUMMY1' AND
             pk.pk_id = ab.pk_id (+)) AND
            (mp1.POBJ_ID = :pn_pobj AND
             pk.mess_merk = '1'))  where a1.MW_ID in (SELECT mw.MW_ID
    FROM   LV_MPRG mp, LV_PK    pk, LV_PKL pkl, VIEW_DEF3_MESSUNG mess, LV_MESSWERT mw, LV_DLOBJ dl, OSI_OBJ ob, LV_ABBRUCH ab 
    WHERE  (mp.DEFMES_ID = mess.DEF_MESS_ID AND
          mp.MPRG_ID = pk.MPRG_ID AND
          pk.PKL_ID = pkl.PKL_ID AND
             pk.PK_ID = mw.PK_ID AND
             mw.DLOBJ_ID = dl.DLOBJ_ID AND
             dl.obj_id = ob.obj_id AND
       mw.MW_ID = a1.MW_ID AND
       mw.SP = a1.sp AND
       ob.KENN = 'DUMMY3' AND
             pk.pk_id = ab.pk_id (+)) AND
            (mp.POBJ_ID = :pn_pobj AND
             pk.mess_merk = '1'));
```

the problem here is its updating the values but writing **NULL** instead of the value. Maybe some one can help me with this query. what am i missing ? so i want all the values in 'WERT_N' in DUMMY_1 to be swapped with WERT_N in DUMMY_3 object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` statement doesn't have a `where` clause.  That means it will update every row in `LV_MESSWERT`.  If your subquery doesn't return a value, the corresponding `LV_MESSWERT` row will be updated to `null`.

If you only want to update the rows where the subquery returns a row, you'd need to add a `where` clause

```
update LV_MESSWERT a1
   set a1.WERT_N = (<<your subquery>>)
 where exists( <<your subquery>> )
```

Comment: HI Justin. Thanks for your quick reply. I could get it work. i wanted to ask you how can i swap the values in these two rows. Dummy1 and Dummy3 Object ? Can you suggest some changes in the query ?

Comment: @user3802070 - I'm not sure that I understand the question.  The queries you posted reference a bunch of tables, it isn't obvious how those tables relate to each other, and `Dummy1` and `Dummy3` are not objects in the query you posted, they're values in tables.  It sounds like you want to ask a separate question.  When you do, post a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem.  Ideally with a much smaller number of tables, some sample data, expected results, etc.

Comment: The above query that i wrote is to copy row value WERT_N for object Dummy1 to Dummy3. If you look closely the two objects are already part of my above query. I want to swap the values of this rows. Do i need to run 2 seperate update statements or there is some other alternate solution ? current solution looks like this: 
update LV_MESSWERT a1
   set a1.WERT_N = (<<subquery for Dummy 1>>)
 where exists( <<subquery for Dummy 3>> )

Comment: @user3802070 - `Dummy1` and `Dummy3` appear to be data values not objects so I'm not completely clear what you are attempting to swap.  If you are attempting to swap data in two different tables (which is what people would normally call "objects" but doesn't appear to be how you're using the term), you'd need likely two separate `update` statements since an `update` can only reference a single object.  Potentially, you could do it with a single `update` of a key-preserved view but without understanding your data model and what table(s) you want to update, I have no idea if that is possible.

Comment: @user3802070 - If you are trying to swap the data in two different rows of the same table, you could do that in a single `update` statement.  You'd likely need to add some conditional logic (i.e. a `case` statement) to your subquery.  Given the complexity of your existing query, it might make more sense to have two separate `update` statements in that case rather than making the existing logic even more complicated.  Factoring some of the logic out into views might let you simplify things enough to make adding the conditional logic more reasonable.

Comment: Thanks i need to swap the data in two different rows of the same table. I think you are right current query is very complicated bringing a case logic in this query would make it more complex. Is there a way to save the values from a subquery for Dummy_1 row in temp_variable and use it in the next update statement for Dummy_3 ?

Comment: @user3802070 - You can certainly create a PL/SQL block and use a local variable.  I'm not sure if you'd need a local scalar variable or whether you'd need a local collection.  If performance isn't a huge concern, you could create a PL/SQL block with a cursor that loops through the rows you want to update and does the swap.